# XSL fo :ValidationException: “fo:table-body” is missing child elements

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo

I tried to get the solution frthis error and none of the other topics really came close to addressing the same problem. As I am new to XSL.

I am getting the below errors.

> fo:table-cell" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:36249) in PER-FPL-FLP-ICR-40 (CLIMB CORRECTION), DU solution 00012999.0019001 (CLIMB CORRECTION), near lid N.00012999.0019001.141 [Tue May 10 15:47:14 IST 2016]
>       com.airbus.ops.publisher.composer.render.RenderEngineWrapperException: Cannot transform document [Tue May 10 15:47:14 IST 2016]
>       Cannot transform document [Tue May 10 15:47:14 IST 2016]
>       javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-cell" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:36249) [Tue May 10 15:47:14 IST 2016]
>       org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-cell" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:36249) [Tue May 10 15:47:14 IST 2016]
>       file:/C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/OpsComposer/N_FCOM_20140905_9848/RENDER/INTERMEDIATE/NP00745.fo:1:36249: "fo:table-cell" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:36249) [Tue May 10 15:47:14 IST 2016]"

```
<fo:block>
<fo:block opsc:lid="N.00012999.0001001.001">
<fo:block font-family="OpsComposer" font-size="9.5pt" widows="2" orphans="2" margin-left="3mm" opsc:lid="N.00012999.0001001.002" text-align="left">
The planner must correct the values for the fuel and the time obtained from the integrated cruise tables with the numbers given in the following tables. The tables which are established for <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">
M .78</fo:inline>
 and long range speed, take into account climbing from the brake release point at <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">
250 kt</fo:inline>
/?<fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">
300 kt</fo:inline>
/?<fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">
M .78</fo:inline>
.</fo:block>
</fo:block>
</fo:block>
<fo:block>
<fo:block opsc:lid="N.00012999.0019001.001" font-family="OpsComposer" font-size="9.5pt">
<fo:block space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" keep-together.within-page="8" keep-with-next.within-page="always">
<fo:block margin-left="3mm" keep-with-next.within-page="always" font-family="OpsComposer" font-size="9.5pt" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="underline">
<fo:inline>
<fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">
M .78</fo:inline>
 AND LONG RANGE SPEED</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:block>
</fo:block>
<fo:block opsc:lid="N.00012999.0019001.140">
<fo:block opsc:lid="N.00012999.0019001.141" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt">
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" hyphenate="false" border-collapse="collapse" fpc:table-omit-header-at-start="true" fpc:table-omit-footer-at-end="true">
<fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
<fo:table-header start-indent="0pt" end-indent="0pt" keep-together.within-page="1">
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block font-family="OpsComposer" font-size="7.9pt" text-align="right" font-style="italic" font-weight="normal">
Continued from the previous page</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block/>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell border-bottom="1pt solid black">
<fo:block/>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-header>
<fo:table-footer start-indent="0pt" end-indent="0pt" keep-together.within-page="1">
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block/>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block font-family="OpsComposer" font-size="7.9pt" text-align="right" font-style="italic" font-weight="normal">
Continued on the following page</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-footer>
<fo:table-body start-indent="0pt" end-indent="0pt">
<fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always" keep-together.within-page="always">
<fo:table-cell/>
</fo:table-row>
<?opsc-table-header-separation 1?>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" hyphenate="false" border-collapse="collapse" border-top="1pt solid black" border-bottom="1pt solid black" border-right="1pt solid black" border-left="1pt solid black" keep-with-next.within-page="6">
<fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="8.229999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="3" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="4" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="5" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="6" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="7" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="8" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="9" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="10" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="11" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="12" column-width="7.059999999999999%"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="13" column-width="14.109999999999998%"/>
<fo:table-header start-indent="0pt" end-indent="0pt" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" keep-together.within-page="4" keep-with-next.within-page="5">
<fo:table-row opsc:lid="N.00012999.0019001.142" border-right="1pt solid black" border-left="1pt solid black" keep-with-next="always" keep-together.within-page="6">
<fo:table-cell padding-left="1pt" padding-right="1pt" column-number="1" number-columns-spanned="13" border-bottom="1pt solid black" text-align="center" display-align="center">
<fo:block>
<fo:block font-family="OpsComposer" font-size="8pt" widows="2" orphans="2" margin-left="0mm" opsc:lid="N.00012999.0019001.143" font-weight="bold">
 CLIMB CORRECTION ON FUEL CONSUMPTION (1000 KG) </fo:block>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row opsc:lid="N.00012999.0019001.144" border-right="1pt solid black" border-left="1pt solid black" keep-with-next="2" keep-together.within-page="1">
<fo:table-cell padding-left="1pt" padding-right="1pt" column-number="1" border-bottom="1pt solid black" border-right="1pt solid black" number-rows-spanned="2" text-align="center" display-align="center">
<fo:block>
<fo:block font-family="OpsComposer" font-size="9.5pt" font-weight="bold">
 FL </fo:block>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-left="1pt" padding-right="1pt" column-number="2" number-columns-spanned="11" border-bottom="1pt solid black" border-right="1pt solid black" text-align="center" display-align="center">
<fo:block>
<fo:block font-family="OpsComposer" font-size="8.9pt">
 WEIGHT AT BRAKE RELEASE (1000 KG) </fo:block>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>`
```

If need more information kindly let me know. Can anybody please guide me .Where I am doing wrong.Thanks in advance .`

Comment: Your title doesn't match your quoted error message.  You have an empty `fo:table-cell` at `<fo:table-cell/>`.

Comment: @TonyGraham....Hi....Now able to resolve the issue.. In that below code if I put underscore  here 'tperfo_body'...the code is working properly.  I didn't understand the logic. Can you please explain the below code. <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="ancestor::PERFORMANCE and TGROUP[contains(string(@TABSTYLE),'tperfo body')][1]">

Comment: `contains(string(@TABSTYLE),'tperfo body')` is testing whether the `TABSTYLE` attribute contains the string "`tperfo body`". (The `string()` is redundant here.)  Presumably the attribute value that appears in your XML is "`tfperfo_body`".