# xsl transformation error :

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am new to xsl ,xslt. I tried to get the solution for this error and none of the other topics really came close to addressing the same problem.

I am getting the below error .

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-cell" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:36249) [Thu May 12 11:33:42 IST 2016]
>   org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-cell" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:36249) [Thu May 12 11:33:42 IST 2016]
>   file:/C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/OpsComposer/N_FCOM_20140905_9064/RENDER/INTERMEDIATE/NP00745.fo:1:36249: "fo:table-cell" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:36249) [Thu May 12 11:33:42 IST 2016]
>   com.airbus.ops.publisher.composer.exception.ManualRenderException: com.airbus.ops.publisher.composer.render.RenderEngineWrapperException: Cannot transform document at com.airbus.ops.publisher.composer.ManualRenderPSLThread.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by: com.airbus.ops.publisher.composer.render.RenderEngineWrapperException: Cannot transform document at com.airbus.ops.publisher.composer.render.RenderEngineWrapper.transformAndRender(Unknown Source) ... 2 more Caused by: com.airbus.fpc.exception.FPCException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:

I have three xsl file . which produce NP00745.html file  .

```
<xsl:stylesheet extension-element-prefixes="saxon" version="2.0" xmlns:fpc="http://airbus.com/fpc" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="no" method="xml" version="1.0"/>

    <xsl:template name="fpc-tmpl-transform-content">
        <xsl:param name="text-transform" select="'none'"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$text-transform='none'">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$text-transform='toupper'">
                <xsl:for-each select="*|text()">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="self::text()">
                            <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                                <xsl:with-param name="text-transform" select="$text-transform"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$text-transform='tolower'">
                <xsl:for-each select="*|text()">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="self::text()">
                            <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(.)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                                <xsl:with-param name="text-transform" select="$text-transform"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fpc:revst">
        <xsl:param name="text-transform" select="'none'"/>
        <!-- <fpc:r> -->
            <xsl:call-template name="fpc-tmpl-transform-content">
                <xsl:with-param name="text-transform" select="$text-transform"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        <!-- </fpc:r> -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fpc:revst" mode="_copy">
        <xsl:param name="text-transform" select="'none'"/>
        <!-- <fpc:r> -->
            <xsl:call-template name="fpc-tmpl-transform-content">
                <xsl:with-param name="text-transform" select="$text-transform"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        <!-- </fpc:r> -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fpc:cocst">
        <xsl:param name="text-transform" select="'none'"/>
        <!-- <fpc:c> -->
            <xsl:call-template name="fpc-tmpl-transform-content">
                <xsl:with-param name="text-transform" select="$text-transform"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        <!-- </fpc:c> -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fpc:cocst" mode="_copy">
        <xsl:param name="text-transform" select="'none'"/>
        <!-- <fpc:c> -->
            <xsl:call-template name="fpc-tmpl-transform-content">
                <xsl:with-param name="text-transform" select="$text-transform"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        <!-- </fpc:c> -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If need more information kindly let me know. Can anybody please guide me .Where I am doing wrong.Thanks in advance .`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154540/xsl-fo-validationexception-fotable-body-is-missing-child-elements.